# Multiplication of bits in twos complement form

Tags: multiplication, bit

Please help me with the following two's complement multiplication logic.

```
                     Actual      cropped
```

Unsigned   5 [101] 3 [011] 15 [001111] 7 [111]

Two’s comp. −3 [101] 3 [011] −9 [110111] −1 [111]

I cant understand how actual multiplication is different for unsigned and two's complement multiplication when bit for both are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplication for signed and unsigned integers is performed by different rules (unlike addition and subtraction, for example).

The same bits can represent different data, actual interpretation depends on type.

Comment: But can u please explain how multiplication works for -3(101) and 3(011) as in example above

Comment: I won't describe how it's implemented in modern CPUs, but the scheme is the following: multiplication is performed on absolute values of operands, and sign of the result is calculated separately. So, abs(-3)*abs(3) = 3*3 = 9 is performed, and sign of the result is then inverted because one of the operands is negative and the other is not. This is the case only for signed operands. Unsigned multiplication doesn't calculate 'absolute' values.